# how to judge a page url starting with http or https in php?

Tags: php, https

how to judge a page url starting with http or https in php?
the problem is that when using https ,the css of page will lost css 
so any method to judge in php?

```
if(...){
    echo 'https:';
}else{
    echo 'http:';
}
```

Comment: Use protocol-relative urls, e.g., `//www.yoursite.com/css/site.css`, which will use what protocol is in use for the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the css and javascript from the same protocol, you can use //

```
<script src='//example.com/path/to/jsfile.js'></script>
<link href='//example.com/path/to/cssfile.css' />
```

If you really want to solve it with php, check the $_SERVER variables from php, http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

```
$_SERVER['HTTPS']
```

should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use protocol less URL for assets such as css files:

```
<link type="stylesheet" href="//site.com/style.css">
```

In php you can determie that by checking `$_SERVER['HTTPS']`;

Answer (score 1):

if the request was sent with HTTPS you will have a extra parameter.[$_SERVER Tutorial](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

```
if( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = "https://www.test.com";
if ( strpos($url, "https") !== FALSE ) {
  echo "https:";
}    
else {
  echo "http:";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to find out if a page is Secure do the following

if( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ) {

but you could also in your html do the following rather than map the css to page to the css in full

~/css/stylesheet.css